# What are brackets `[]` doing in Matlab, if not filled with numbers?

Tags: matlab, brackets, notation

**What are brackets `[]` doing in Matlab, if not filled with numbers?**

Let's assume we have some objects `obj1`, `obj2` and `obj3` of a `ClassA`. Apparently it's possible to combine them with brackets in a .. don't know, what it actually is

```
objects = [obj1 obj2 obj3];

>> class(objects)

ans =

ClassA

>> objects

objects = 

  1x3 ClassA handle

  Properties:
    name
    ...
```

1. Whats this called?
2. How to iteratively build such thing?
   `objects = []; objects(end+1) = current_obj;` does not work
   `objects{end+1} = current_obj;` creates a cell
3. How can one convert to this e. g. from a cell with objects?

When using the `[]` notation again on a field it gives

```
K>> [objects.name]

ans =

Object1Object2Object3

K>> class([objects.name])

ans =

char
```

Comment: A square bracket creates a vector or matrix

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[obj1 obj2 obj3]` is an *array* of objects of class `ClassA`, just like `[1 2 3]` is an array of numbers.

If you type `a = []; a(2) = 1`, MATLAB will return `a` as `[0 1]`, in other words it will fill any unspecified elements of `a` with a default element which, in the case of numbers, is zero.

When you type `objects = []; objects(2) = current_obj`, MATLAB similarly attempts to put `current_obj` in the requested position 2 of `objects`, and then to fill the unspecified elements with default objects of class `ClassA`. To do this, it calls the constructor of `ClassA`, but you need to know that it calls the constructor *with no input arguments*.

Therefore, if you want to be able to support this sort of array filling with objects of your class, you need to implement the class constructor so that it will not error when called with zero input arguments. For example, you could simply check `nargin`, and if it's zero, supply some default inputs, otherwise accept whatever inputs were provided.

By the way, by default `[]` is of class `double`. If you want to create an empty array of class `ClassA`, you can use `objects = ClassA.empty`. `empty` is a built-in method of *all* MATLAB classes. You may find that you avoid some errors by making sure that you don't accidentally attempt to concatenate `double`s with objects of class `ClassA`.

Comment: `objects = ClassA.empty` is a good hint. I'd use cells, but the `[objects.property]` syntax is very convenient to gather property values of objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need an empty array of objects, use some object you have and index "nothing" (from 2 to 1):

```
x=obj1(2:1)
```

Result is an empty array with a matching type. Here you can append using `x(end+1)`. Alternatively you can use similar code to append. If x does not exist it will be created with a matching type.

```
if exist('x','var')
   x(end+1)=obj
else
   x(1)=obj
end
```

Comment: If you need an empty array of objects, use `ClassName.empty`. `empty` is a built-in method of all MATLAB classes, defined just for this purpose.

Comment: @SamRoberts: never noticed such a function exists. Using `empty` is definitely the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is creating structures. What I would do is create the same structure for `objects` and then overwrite the 1st index with your first object, and then iterate through the rest:

```
% Assume we have classA.m file available
obj1 = classA();
obj2 = classA();
obj3 = classA();

objects = obj1;
objects(end+1) = obj2;
objects(end+1) = obj3;
```

Comment: They are not structures, they are arrays.

Comment: @SamRoberts, I was referring to the obj itself. The question was what are those things called. I understand that the variable `objects` is an array of structs.

Comment: `objects` is not an array of structs, it is an array of objects of class `ClassA`. There are no structs, or arrays of structs, mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

## Square brackets are for concatenation

If you have square brackets with elements between them, you are concatenating the elements.

The elements can abe scalars, strings, vectors, matrices and so on.

## Example

Assuming that the name fields of the objects struct contains a string, you can concatenate all of them like so:

```
[objects.name]
```

The result will be:

```
[objects(1).name objects(2).name ... objects(end).name]
```